# PHP server problem

Tags: php

I've build a web site that get source code of the link entered by the user using(HTML DOM), then checks the source depending on standards.
the problem is some web sites can't evaluate. 
 this is [My Web Site link](http://awaef.org/index.php) you can check from here.

when you enter google URL in the text-box, the web site functionality works successful, but when trying the example http://www.alwatan.com.sa/Default.aspx it doesn't work. no information appear.

can one help me?

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://www.alwatan.com.sa/Default.aspx` automatically redirects to `http://www.alwatan.com.sa/Default.aspx?issueno=3902`

If you enter the URL with the query string, your application works (presumably) as intended.

I imagine there is no content at `http://www.alwatan.com.sa/Default.aspx`, and the `issueno` is a required parameter.

Comment: Dear Ross,thanks for your response.I've understand what do you mean. but there is another situation, I've try another link which doesn't have a query  [link] http://www.al-jazirah.com/  but doesn't work. although [link] http://www.alriyadh.com/ which has the same format syntax works. I can't see where is the problem. if any body know plz tell me :).